# Elm Lift function

Tags: elm

I am a newbie to the elm.

According to the document,

```
lift2 : (a -> b -> c) -> Signal a -> Signal b -> Signal c

Combine two signals with a given function.
```

Can I have a way to do something like this?

```
(a->b->c) -> Signal a -> b -> Signal c
```

Is it true that the only way to do is first use  `constant : a -> Signal a` and then use `lift2`

Just curious, is there a way to quickly let `Signal a -> a`, if possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to write a function with the signature `Signal a -> a`.

However, it should be possible to write `(a -> b -> c) -> Signal a -> b -> Signal c`

Is this what you wanted?

```
foo : (a->b->c) -> Signal a -> b -> Signal c
foo f sa b = (flip f) b <~ sa
```